# Need to assign an ID to an option of a wxComboBox and retrieve the option's id when selected

Tags: python, combobox, wxpython

I have a list of clients retrieved from a database along with their id's.
I want to add them to a wxComboBox and when they are selected retrieve the id not the option text.  The clients have been sorted alphabetically so the id's are not in order.

I have tried the following

```
    clients = get_client_list()
            for client in clients:
                self.client_comboBox.Append(client.name, client.id)
```

This does not work.
I've also tried using

> getSelection()

but this just gives me the options position in the drop down list.
What I need to do is retrieve the id of the selected option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to build the item that you are appending to include a delimiter, which can then be easily `split` when chosen.
If you construct the item to be client_id+tab+client_name, its a simply process to split the chosen string, to get the client id.

```
import wx

class Myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        clients = ["Joe Bloggs","Arthur C Goggins","Gary Sable"]
        client_ids = ["10001","00326","51001"]
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.cbx = wx.ComboBox(self.panel, -1, value="Choose an Option", pos=(10,30), size=(300,30),choices="")
        for item in range(len(clients)):
            self.cbx.Append(client_ids[item]+"\t"+clients[item])
        self.cbx.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.on_selection)
        self.txt1 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "Selected Value", pos=(10,200), size=(300,30))
        self.txt2 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "Selected Selection", pos=(10,230), size=(300,30))
        self.txt3 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "Selected String", pos=(10,260), size=(300,30))
        self.txt4 = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1, "Selected Id", pos=(10,290), size=(300,30))

    def on_selection(self, evt):
        Choice = self.cbx.GetValue()
        self.txt1.SetValue(Choice)
        Choice = self.cbx.GetSelection()
        self.txt2.SetValue(str(Choice))
        Choice = self.cbx.GetStringSelection()
        self.txt3.SetValue(Choice)
        Id = Choice.split("\t",1)[0]
        self.txt4.SetValue(Id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = wx.App()
    Myframe().Show()
    App.MainLoop()
```

[image]